# Changing position of year in natbib with plainnat style

Tags: natbib

I am using Miktex with Natbib such as:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{model}
```

When the bibliography prints out the author year is at the end. I need it to go after the list of authors. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 7):

Copy the file `plainnat.bst` to `myplainnat.bst` and save it into your document directory. Then look into this file at the lower half you'll find the definitions for the different entries, e.g. for `book`:

```
FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
      editor format.key output
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
    }
    { new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.isbn output
  format.doi output
  format.url output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

now you can change the order which is in your case move up the line for the date.

Comment: This is great. How do I add brackets for year, please?