# Natbib: LASTNAME, Firstname (Year) style

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I would like BibTeX citations to appear as

> LASTNAME, Firstname (year): Title etc.

in the references. There should be no "bibliography key" [...] in the references section, and citations should appear as (Lastname, year) in the text.

Currently, I am using Natbib and [natdin.bst](http://w3-mediapool.hm.edu/mediapool/media/bibliothek_2/bib_lokal/zotero/natdin.bst) with the definition

```
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{}
```

to hide the keys. However, the year is still printed at the end of the citation and not in parentheses right after the author. How could that be achieved?

I am aware of [Changing position of year in natbib with plainnat style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9192/changing-position-of-year-in-natbib-with-plainnat-style), but the natdin.bst file seems pretty different and I'm not sure about the right places to tweak it. Is there maybe an existing style that suits my needs?

A minor little extra would be to only output "(Hrsg.)" (Hrsg. = Herausgeber = publisher in German) once even if there are several publishers.

Comment: I recommend the changing to `biblatex`.

Comment: I second Marco's recommendation. Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex

Comment: Run `latex makebst` and answer about 100 questions, you'll get a proper `.bst` style file of any style you want. See [`custom-bib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment `biblatex` offers a very user friendly solution.

The style `authoryear` accomplishes your request of ordering and style. To set a colon after the year you can redefine the separator `\labelnamepunct`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Example cite \cite{companion}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]