# How can i change the position of the year in the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I would like to change the position of the year in the bibliography using plainnat.bst. I've tried using the answer to this question([Changing position of year in natbib with plainnat style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9192/changing-position-of-year-in-natbib-with-plainnat-style)). I've tried this for the book section and it remains at the end of the reference, but the year will also follow the author.

I've also tried this for article and then nothing changes.

At this moment i'm using:
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: If there is no reason to stick with natbib and bibtex, i recommend using `biblatex` and `biber` instead. Biblatex is much more flexible making it easier to modify things.